# Application takes more time to load in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have three different app with JAVA code (business logic), i tested my application and took production build using sencha cmd. Its work fine in local. When i moved my same application to production server it takes 39 sec to load app (minified version of js). I need some guidance in taking build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to identify the code where it is taking time like if some unnecessary requests are sent to server or some other code is executing which is not needed while loading the app.

Comment: @Rajinder.. But it works fine in local network. this issue came when i moved to production.

Comment: But that doesn't mean anything. You still need to follow Rajinder's advice. Local network is almost *always* going to be faster than production environments since you don't have to deal with latency issues as much. So I would look at remote requests (e.g., loading large JSON requests, etc.) to see where your bottleneck is.

Comment: If you are using google chrome then the load times for the different files and requests will be on the network tab in dev tools which should provide some insight into where the bottleneck is

Comment: Thanks for info. My production app.js size is 800 kb and its minified. is it fine ?